# iPhone SDK: How to make a label view a cgpoint?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uilabel, cgpoint

I have a CGPoint:

```
ballVelocity = CGPointMake(kBallSpeedX,kBallSpeedX);
```

and i would like a label (xVelocityLabel) to view the "ballVelocity.x" value of the CGPoint.
I have tried:

```
[xVelocityLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ballVelocity.x]];
```

Thanks for your help because I am new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change '%f' instead of '%@'.

```
[xVelocityLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", ballVelocity.x]];
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: He'll probably be better of with `"%.2f"` or similiar but +1 for correct answer.

Comment: this was exactly what i was looking for and i just copied and pasted and it worked perfectly. THX!

Answer (score 0):

`[xVelocityLabel setText:NSStringFromCGPoint(ballVelocity)];`

Answer (score 0):

```
ballVelocity.x // this is a float value.
```

So you have to convert it in NSString before set it on UILabel.

for set a value on xVelocityLabel, the value should be in string format. see this conversion-

```
NSString *strNumber = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:ballVelocity.x] stringValue];

[xVelocityLabel setText:strNumber];
```

Thank you!